# Javascript replace regex not working with capitalization

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is killing me ... Let's get right to it, and show my problem with the code I already have:

```
if (data.term) {
    var search = data.term.toLowerCase();
    var element = data.text;
    var rgxp = new RegExp(search, 'gi');
    var repl = '<span style="color:#F00">' + data.term + '</span>';
    element = element.replace(rgxp, repl);
}
console.log(element);
```

data.text -> "Pinus pinaster" 
(first word capitalized, second word isn't)

Right out of the gate I put the search term (or terms) all in lowercase cause people can input right about anything ... Pin pIn PIN etc etc etc

The final result of my code is something like

```
<span style="color:#F00">Pin</span>us <span style="color:#F00">Pin</span>aster
```

Notice the second word ... capitalized :-|

I started with the flag "g" on my regex ... thought that changing that to "gi" would solve it but no.

In dispair ... tried this

```
if (data.term) {
    var search = data.t.toLowerCase();
    var element = data.text;
    var rgxp1 = new RegExp(search, 'g');
    var rgxp2 = new RegExp(search, 'gi');
    var repl = '<span style="color:#F00">' + data.term + '</span>';

    element = element.replace(rgxp1, repl);
    element = element.replace(rgxp2, repl);

}
```

But with this I get

```
<span style="color:#F00">pin</span>us <span style="color:#F00">pin</span>aster
```

Any help? I want to highlight the searched term leaving the original string as is.

Comment: It's a typo ... forgot to change to data.term

Comment: can you provide value of `data`?

Comment: data is a huge object ... but for this example data.text being "Pinus pinaster" is perfect. data.term is user inputed... might be Pin, pin, pIn, PIN or whatever users remember to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [Regex Capture Groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references).

Basically, just wrap the regex in parentheses, then use `$1` in the replacement string to access whatever was captured in the string.  This will retain the original case.  Also, use both the `g` and `i` flags.

Example:

```
if (data.term) {
    var search = data.term.toLowerCase();
    var element = data.text;
    var rgxp = new RegExp('(' + search + ')', 'gi'); // add parentheses to 'capture' the matched string for use later.
    var repl = '<span style="color:#F00">$1</span>'; // `$1` says, "grab whatever was captured and stick it here"

    element = element.replace(rgxp, repl);
    console.log(element); // <span style="color:#F00">Pin</span>us <span style="color:#F00">pin</span>aster
}
```

And here's a working [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o8ztg9yg/).  Cheers.

Comment: It realy sucks not being good neither experienced with regexes ... I don't understand how some people manage to understand them so well!
Your solution worked perfecty. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AfonsoGomes No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the jquery tag is not part of your question, I would remove it.

data.text is not assigned within the block.
As far as I can see repl should contain the string you want.